# Add Attributes fields on Inventory Lookup

Tags: acumatica

I want to add the attributes for my inventory lookup on Sales Order and Purchase Order, does anyone know how to? or any ideas?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I tried to work on Sales Order and tried to modify the SOSiteFilterStatus DAC setting it on constant values, but no where I would dynamically add depending on the attributes required by the item class

Comment: u mean the attribute values in stockitem?

Comment: yes! on the Add Item dialog screen of Sales Order and Purchase Order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer below code example to include Attributes Columns in Selector and Grid Control utilizing out-of-box `CRAttributesFieldAttribute`.

Declare a class `PXAddAtttributeColumns` inherited from `CRAttributesFieldAttribute`.

```cs
public class PXAddAtttributeColumns : CRAttributesFieldAttribute
{
    string[] _names;
    bool _IsForSelector;

    public PXAddAtttributeColumns(string[] names, Type entityType, Type entityIDField, Type classIDField, bool IsForSelector = true)
        : base(entityType, entityIDField, classIDField)
    {
        _names = names;
        _IsForSelector = IsForSelector;
    }

    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
        this._IsActive = true;
        base.CacheAttached(sender);
    }

    protected override void AttributeFieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldState state, string attributeName, int idx)
    {
        if (_names.Any(attributeName.Equals))
        {
            //Out-of-box DisplayName is prefixed with "$Attributes$-" - if you need to take that off.
            state.DisplayName = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.DisplayName)) ? (state.DisplayName.Replace("$Attributes$-", "")) : attributeName;
            state.Visible = true;
            //Requires AutoGenerateColumns="AppendDynamic" for PXGrid Control for dynamic Attribute columns creation
            state.Visibility = (_IsForSelector) ? PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible : PXUIVisibility.Dynamic;
        }
        base.AttributeFieldSelecting(sender, e, state, attributeName, idx);
    }

    public override void CommandPreparing(PXCache sender, PXCommandPreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.CommandPreparing(sender, e);

        if (e.BqlTable == null && aggregateAttributes && sender.GetItemType().IsDefined(typeof(PXProjectionAttribute), true))
        {
            e.BqlTable = _BqlTable;
        }
    }
}
```

To include attributes as Columns in `Inventory Look up`, declare DAC Extension as below:

```cs
public class InventoryItemPXExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>
{
    #region Attributes

    public abstract class attributes : IBqlField { }

    [PXAddAtttributeColumns(new[] { "ASSETID", "HWMODEL" },
            typeof(CSAnswerType.inventoryAnswerType),
            typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID),
            typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID))]
    public virtual string[] Attributes { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Fields will show up as below:

[image]

Search can be Enabled on Attribute Columns by setting `FilterByAllFields` to `True`

[image]

To include attributes as Columns in `Sales Order Details Grid`, declare DAC Extension as below:

```cs
public class SOLineExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
{
    public abstract class itemAttributes : IBqlField { }

    [PXAddAtttributeColumns(new[] { "ASSETID", "HWMODEL" },
            typeof(CSAnswerType.inventoryAnswerType),
            typeof(SOLine.inventoryID),
            typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID), false)]
    public virtual string[] ItemAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to specify `AutoGenerateColumns="AppendDynamic"` for `PXGrid` control dynamic Attribute columns creation

[image]

Fields will show up as below:

[image]

To include attributes as Columns in grid of `Add Stock Item` Dialog, declare DAC Extension as below:

```cs
public class SOSiteStatusSelectedExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOSiteStatusSelected>
{
    public abstract class itemAttributes : IBqlField { }

    [PXAddAtttributeColumns(new[] { "ASSETID", "HWMODEL" },
            typeof(CSAnswerType.inventoryAnswerType),
            typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID),
            typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID), false)]
    public virtual string[] ItemAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to specify `AutoGenerateColumns="AppendDynamic"` for `PXGrid` control dynamic Attribute columns creation

[image]

Fields will show up as below:

[image]

Note: This example is applicable to 5.3 series – Build 5.30.1367 onwards.

Comment: @DChhapgar In new Build CSAnswerType.inventoryAnswerType is not present. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated solution for versions later than 20R1:**

Below is the sample scenario to add custom attributes to both `CustomerID` and `InventoryID` lookups of Sales Orders (SO301000) screen.

1. Create the required attributes from Attributes (CS205000) screen.
2. Add the necessary attribute to the corresponding Customer Classes (AR201000) screen to be added to the `CustomerID` lookup and to the corresponding Item Classes (IN201000) screen to be added to the `InventoryID` lookup.
3. Create a new Attribute class `CustomerAttributeSetFieldsAttribute` extending `CustomerActiveAttribute` (since it is used in `CustomerID`) and override SetColumns by rewriting the same in order to change the FieldList and HeaderList.

```cs
public class CustomerAttributeSetFieldsAttribute : CustomerActiveAttribute
{
    public static void SetColumns(PXCache cache, string field, string[] fieldList, string[] headerList)
    {
        PXSelectorAttribute.SetColumns(cache, field, fieldList, headerList);
        foreach (CustomerAttributeSetFieldsAttribute attr in cache.GetAttributes(field).OfType<CustomerAttributeSetFieldsAttribute>())
        {
            attr._FieldList = fieldList;
            attr._HeaderList = headerList;
        }
    }
}
```

4. Override Initialize method and call Activate for activating the attribute by passing proper cache - *BAccountR* - for `CustomerID` and *InventoryItem* - for `InventoryID`. Also, call SetColumns from the custom attribute for `CustomerID` `CustomerAttributeSetFieldsAttribute` and `PXSelectorAttribute` for `InventoryID` and pass the cache type (where the lookup is present), field (field name), fieldList (list of names of all the fields including the attributes) and headerList (list of names of all the headers including the attributes).
5. Override the attributes to merge the newly added attribute to `CustomerID` by adding `CustomerAttributeSetFields` to SOOrder_CustomerID_CacheAttached method.

```cs
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        //for InventoryID lookup
        CR.CRAttributesFieldAttribute.Activate(Base.Caches[typeof(InventoryItem)]);
        PXSelectorAttribute.SetColumns(Base.Caches[typeof(SOLine)],
          "InventoryID", new string[] { "InventoryCD", "Descr", "itemClassID", "Color_ATTRIBUTES" },
           new string[] { "InventoryCD", "Descr", "itemClassID", "$Attributes$-Color" });
            
        //for CustomerID lookup
        CR.CRAttributesFieldAttribute.Activate(Base.Caches[typeof(BAccountR)]);

        CustomerAttributeSetFieldsAttribute.SetColumns(Base.Caches[typeof(SOOrder)],
          "CustomerID", new string[] { "AcctCD", "acctName", "COMPREV_Attributes" },
           new string[] { "AcctCD", "acctName", "$Attributes$-Company Revenue" });
    }

    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [CustomerAttributeSetFields]
    protected virtual void SOOrder_CustomerID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
    }
}
```

**Note**: Since Customer DAC is derived from BAccount and CustomerActive attribute is derived from Customer, it has the cache type BAccountR and only the attributes which are of the same cache type are available to add to the CustomerID popup. If the user needs to add other attributes of different cache type, it will be better to create a new Attribute and use that instead of CustomerActive.