# Attributes Field Not Showing Attribute Value on All Pages

Tags: acumatica

I have a field which shows the attribute of an item called "Coating." I added this field via the Layout Editor to two existing screens I am customizing: The Sales Price and Sales Price Worksheets pages. On the Sales Price Worksheet page, the coatings show up just fine:

[image]

However, on the Sales Price page, they do not:

[image]

I have the exact same element in both page customization in the Layout Editor contained in the respected grids: InventoryItem__COATING_Attributes. Checking the Attributes tab of the element, they both have the same code:

```
protected string[] _Attributes;

/// <summary>
/// Reserved for internal use.
/// Provides the values of attributes associated with the item.
/// For more information see the <see cref="CSAnswers"/> class.
/// </summary>
[CRAttributesField(typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID))]
```

As far as I can tell, everything is exactly the same. I even checked the results of the query that is sent for both pages' select statements and they are properly returning similar statements to show the coatings for each element.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: Is this field being saved in the Database?

Comment: Yes, it is being pulled from the CSAnswers table. It is an Item Attribute.

Comment: Attributes are working with Graph's Cache. If in the Cache there is no Collection for CSAnswers attribute won't work. Try to add `PXSelect<CSAnswers>` to  the Graph where Attribute does not work

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the issue. I also checked the page that is working and the base page, as well as the extension, don't have a `PXSelect<CSAnswers>` view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the attribute works as expected on the Sales Price Worksheets screen due to the sample posted in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616603/add-attributes-fields-on-inventory-lookup/39629691#39629691) and the lack of delegate declared for the ARPriceWorksheetMaint.Details data view:

```
public class ARPriceWorksheetMaint : PXGraph<ARPriceWorksheetMaint, ARPriceWorksheet>
{
    ...
    [PXImport(typeof(ARPriceWorksheet))]
    public PXSelectJoin<ARPriceWorksheetDetail,
            LeftJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<ARPriceWorksheetDetail.inventoryID>>>, Where<ARPriceWorksheetDetail.refNbr, Equal<Current<ARPriceWorksheet.refNbr>>>,
            OrderBy<Asc<ARPriceWorksheetDetail.priceType, Asc<ARPriceWorksheetDetail.priceCode, Asc<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Asc<ARPriceWorksheetDetail.breakQty>>>>>> Details;
    ...
}
```

On the Sales Price screen though, there is a records() delegate returning only instances of the ARSalesPrice DAC, preventing the attribute from obtaining its values from database:

```
public virtual IEnumerable records()
{
    ...
    foreach (PXResult<ARSalesPrice> res in QSelect(this, Records.View.BqlSelect, new object[] { filter.PriceType, filter.PriceType, filter.PriceType == PriceTypes.Customer ? priceCode : null, filter.PriceType == PriceTypes.CustomerPriceClass ? priceCode : null, priceCode, filter.InventoryID, filter.InventoryID, filter.EffectiveAsOfDate, filter.EffectiveAsOfDate, filter.EffectiveAsOfDate, filter.ItemClassID, filter.ItemClassID, filter.InventoryPriceClassID, filter.InventoryPriceClassID, filter.OwnerID, filter.OwnerID, filter.MyWorkGroup, filter.WorkGroupID, filter.WorkGroupID }))
    {
        ARSalesPrice price = res;
        yield return price;
    }
    ...
}
```

In order to show the attribute on the Sales Price screen, you should modify the Records data view and override its delegate to return instances of both the ARSalesPrice and InventoryItem DACs:

```
public class ARSalesPriceMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<ARSalesPriceMaint>
{
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXSelectJoin<ARSalesPrice,
        LeftJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID>>>,
        Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<INItemStatus.inactive>,
        And<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<INItemStatus.toDelete>,
        And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceType>, Equal<PriceTypes.allPrices>, Or<ARSalesPrice.priceType, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceType>>>>,
        And2<Where<ARSalesPrice.customerID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceCode>>, Or<ARSalesPrice.custPriceClassID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceCode>>, Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.priceCode>, IsNull>>>,
        And2<Where<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID, Equal<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.inventoryID>>, Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.inventoryID>, IsNull>>,
        And2<Where2<Where2<Where<ARSalesPrice.effectiveDate, LessEqual<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.effectiveAsOfDate>>, Or<ARSalesPrice.effectiveDate, IsNull>>,
        And<Where<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate, GreaterEqual<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.effectiveAsOfDate>>, Or<ARSalesPrice.expirationDate, IsNull>>>>,
        Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.effectiveAsOfDate>, IsNull>>,
        And<Where2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.itemClassID>, IsNull,
                Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.itemClassID>, Equal<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>>,
            And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.inventoryPriceClassID>, IsNull,
                Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.inventoryPriceClassID>, Equal<InventoryItem.priceClassID>>>,
            And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.ownerID>, IsNull,
                Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.ownerID>, Equal<InventoryItem.priceManagerID>>>,
            And2<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.myWorkGroup>, Equal<False>,
                     Or<InventoryItem.priceWorkgroupID, InMember<CurrentValue<ARSalesPriceFilter.currentOwnerID>>>>,
            And<Where<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.workGroupID>, IsNull,
                Or<Required<ARSalesPriceFilter.workGroupID>, Equal<InventoryItem.priceWorkgroupID>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>,
            OrderBy<Asc<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID,
                    Asc<ARSalesPrice.priceType,
                    Asc<ARSalesPrice.uOM, Asc<ARSalesPrice.breakQty, Asc<ARSalesPrice.effectiveDate>>>>>>> Records;


    public IEnumerable records()
    {
        var startRow = PXView.StartRow;
        int totalRows = 0;

        foreach (ARSalesPrice salesPrice in Base.Records.View.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, PXView.Searches, 
            PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalRows))
        {
            var item = PXSelectorAttribute.Select<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID>(Records.Cache, salesPrice) as InventoryItem;
            var res = new PXResult<ARSalesPrice, InventoryItem>(salesPrice, item);
            yield return res;
        }
        PXView.StartRow = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ruslan, you are an Acumatica Wizard! Thank you so much! That works perfectly!

Comment: My pleasure, Eric :-)